# HtmlDropDownListFor in Edit View how to retain current value in the Select List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my edit View, I have a form with multiple input boxes (`EditorFor`), each input has a drop down of 'operators' which has values like `=, <>, IN, NOT IN`. Every time I enter the edit view, the selected DropDown values are being 'reset'.

The ViewModel that is being passed in does contain the correct values, however I can't get the select list to default to that selected value.

**DropDown**

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JcrOrgBudgetGroupOp, new SelectList(OperatorsHelper.StrOperators,selectedValue:Model.JcrOrgBudgetGroupOp)
```

**StrOperators**

```
   public static class OperatorsHelper
   {
      public static IEnumerable<string> StrOperators = new List<string>
      {
        "=",
        "<>",
        "IN",
        "NOT IN"
    };
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure `Model.JcrOrgBudgetGroupOp` has one of those string values ?

Comment: Debugging the Edit ActionMethod in the controller, I see the ViewModel has value for `JcrOrgBudgetGroupOp `

Comment: What values is that ? One of those string values ? Then it should work. I just copied and pasted to a local project and it worked fine.

Comment: The value is `NOT IN` when the view is rendered the value is `=`

Comment: That option also worked for me. Check whether you have a white space before/after those words

Comment: There is white space at the end `"NOT IN "`

Comment: So that is where your problem is. Trim it(better do it when you save if you are doing that)

Comment: Trimming white space worked. Thank you!

Comment: Note that you do not need the 2nd parameter in the `SelectList` constructor (`selectedValue:Model.JcrOrgBudgetGroupOp`)

Comment: You are correct, the selected value is now being properly displayed from the View Model with out specifying `selectedValue:`

Answer (score 0):

First, creating `SelectList` in view can sometimes be problematic. `DropDownListFor` does not require `SelectList`: merely `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. The recommended way to do this always is to do something like:

```
public static class OperatorsHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> StrOperators = new List<string>
    {
        return new[] { "=", "<>", "IN", "NOT IN" }.Select(op => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = op,
            Value = op
        });
    };
}
```

Then:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JcrOrgBudgeGroupOp, OperatorsHelper.StrOperators)
```

Razor will then automatically create the `SelectList` *and* select the appropriate item.

The other thing to be aware of is that the "selected" value is actually the value that's in `ModelState`, not necessarily what's on `Model`. Importantly, `ModelState` is composed of values from `Request` and `ViewBag`/`ViewData`, first, and then `Model` as a last resort. In other words, if you were to post field named `jcrOrgBudgetGroupOp`, pass a value for an action param from the URL for `jcrOrgBudgetGroupOp`, or set `ViewBag.JcrOrgBudgetGroupOp` (casing doesn't matter in either case), that value will always be what is selected.